# How can I export my graphviz tree graph into a jpg that saves in a folder chosen

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, image-graphviz

I got this code using graphviz, it eventually generates my graph but I would like to have the graph generated saved in my root folder. exist a way to do it?

````
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
tree_data = export_graphviz(dtc, out_file=None, feature_names=features_names) 
my_tree = graphviz.Source(tree_data, format='jpg') 
#my_tree.render("/Users/EsteArell/Desktop/Python_Machine".format(jpg))
my_tree```
````

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the recommended one but it didn't work. So I figure out this solution:
This worked for me although with two lines but worked.

````
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
tree_data = export_graphviz(dtc, out_file=None, feature_names=features_names) 
my_tree = graphviz.Source(tree_data, directory ='...own directory') 
my_tree.save(filename='prueba2.jpg', directory='...own directory')
my_tree.render(filename='prueba2',directory='...own directory',view = True, format='jpg')```
````